# Why won't sikuli script click on the image?

Tags: java, sikuli

I am totally new to sikuli, and trying to perform a simple click on the image screenshot, which has become a rocket science for me.

FYI - I took a screenshot of the google logo and saved it on my machine. However, if I fetch the actual google logo image url, then the script works.

Is this the right way to use image screenshots?

```
public class TestGenericButton {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // Open the main page of Google Code in the default web browser
        browse(new URL("http://code.google.com"));

        // Create a screen region object that corresponds to the default monitor in full screen 
        ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();

        // Specify an image as the target to find on the screen
        //URL imageURL = new URL("http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.gif");
        URL imageURL = new URL("img\\google.gif");
        Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageURL);

        // Wait for the target to become visible on the screen for at most 5 seconds
        // Once the target is visible, it returns a screen region object corresponding
        // to the region occupied by this target
        ScreenRegion r = s.wait(imageTarget,5000);

        // Display "Hello World" next to the found target for 3 seconds
        Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
        canvas.addLabel(r, "Hello World").display(3);

        // Click the center of the found target
        Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
        mouse.rightClick(r.getCenter());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you see?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the way to create an ImageTarget.  You have an image in a file that you want to use, so you need to pass a `File`, not a `URL`.

Per [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/ImageTarget#Creating_an_Image_Target), instead of

```
    URL imageURL = new URL("img\\google.gif");
    Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageURL);
```

do

```
    File imageFile = new File("img\\google.gif");  // assumes your working directory is set right...
    Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the imageURL, and this method should do the clicking part :)

```
private void click(String image) throws FindFailed{

    Screen screen = new Screen();

    Pattern pattern = new Pattern(image).similar((float) 0.7);

    if(screen.find(pattern)!=null){ 
        screen.mouseMove(pattern); 
        screen.click(pattern); 
    }
    }
```